# How to define a string array in java and use it in switch case

Tags: java, arrays, string

> Hi dear friends, I want to define a String array in java and use every
>   cells of that array in switch-case in java to count every string
>   elements.for example  can you you help me to fix it thanks.

```
int i=20;
String [] str =new String[i];
string[0]="This";
string[1]="is";
string[2]="a";
string[3]="Test";
string[4]="This";
string[5]="This";
string[6]="a";
string[7]="a";
string[8]="a";
string[20]="Test";
switch(i)
{
case(0):this++
break;
case(1):is++
break;
case(2):a++
break;
case(3):test++
break;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you wouldn't want to use a Hashmap<String, Integer> , and then for all input words increment the int for the string?

Comment: What do you suppose `this++` would do?

Comment: Please get acquainted with the basics of the `Java` language specifically its syntax and reserved words. `this++` is most likely not what you think it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to enumerate all the different possible strings in the array is generally a bad idea and not the correct way to write your program. Sure your example works, but what would happen if your set of possible strings was not just {'this', 'is', 'a', 'test'}, but instead had say 10000 elements? What if you didn't know exactly what `String` elements were in the array? As a previous user mentioned, you want to use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

```
String[] arr = yourStringArray; //wherever your Strings are coming from
Map<String, Integer> strCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>; //this stores the strings you find
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String str = arr[i];
    if (strCounts.containsKey(str)) {
        strCounts.get(str) += 1; //if you've already seen the String before, increment count
    } else {
        strCounts.put(str, 1); //otherwise, add the String to the HashMap, along with a count (1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While i don't really understand what you are trying to do, here are my two cents. You are probably getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is because when you create an array of size `20`, it can hold exactly 20 items. From range `0` to `19`. So trying to do `string[20]="Test";` will give an error because it's out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
int count;
String currentWord;
Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(mySentence);
while(tokenizer.hasNext()){
count = null;
currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
count = wordMap.get(currentWord);
if(count == null) wordMap.put(currentWord, 1);
else wordMap.put(currentWord, ++count);
}
```